# In Lean, why is the exact tactic necessary when the goal is the same as a hypothesis?

Tags: lean, design, tactic

In Lean, when proving basic theorems, one runs into the following kind of thing:

```
import tactic
variables (P : Prop)

example : P → P :=
begin
  intro p,
  exact p,
end
```

After the `intro p,` step, the tactic state is

```
P : Prop
p : P
⊢ P
```

At this point, we need to use the `exact` tactic to close the goal. All `exact` seems to do is to tell Lean that the hypothesis `p` is the same (syntactically? definitionally?) as the target.  It *seems* as if it would be a reasonable design goal (in the interest of efficiency) to have Lean automatically close the goal once the target is at least *syntactically* identical to one of the hypotheses.

Is this a design choice, or is there some deeper reason why this doesn't happen, and what is it?

Comment: You can use the so-called finishing tactics to do trivial work for you.

Comment: Pretty new to it all, so haven't run into that one yet!  I'm slowly learning those shortcuts (like using anonymous constructors and such) and making sure that I know how they translate to a more verbose proof.  I suspect that there's a good reason why certain tactic states don't automatically close, though, which is why I asked this question, just to see if I can get some insight into how lean works/was designed.

Comment: The `assumption` tactic will effectively try `exact h` for each `h` in the local context, until one works. It could be an interesting experiment to modify the tactic monad (or introduce a new interactive tactic mode) that calls `try {assumption}` after each tactic. This would have a significant performance penalty in some parts of the library.

Comment: @RobLewis  That's an interesting take on it, that it's about *performance*. I guess in order for goals to automatically close, it really *would* have to check$-$after *every* step$-$to see if the goal matched a hypothesis.  I can see how that would significantly reduce performance.

Comment: @RobLewis That mode could do `try { assumption }` at the very end of the block, which is more modest of a change.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My take on that is that, in their first approximation, tactics are just ways to build terms (typically proof terms), so it is expected to have basic tactics that closely correspond to the various term formers. In particular, in your example

- `intro x` for `λ x, …`
- `exact e` for `e`.

This hopefully justifies the *existence* of a basic tactic like `exact`.

And it may also justify why, unless you ask for it, no automation happens. Consider using tactics to build terms, and imagine `end` would just close goals using any tactic:

```
def fst {a : Type} : (a,a) → a :=
begin intro x, cases x with x1 x2, end
```

Now there are *two* assumptions that can be used, but the choice *certainly* matters.

But when using more advanced tactics, some of these *do* have such automation built in, e.g. [`simpa`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/tactic/simpa.html).

Comment: I think that the idea that tactics are used to form *terms* (in a more verbose and readable/understandable way) is probably the important point here, and it's one that I'm still thinking about, since most of what I've done is go through a bunch of tutorials, where I've *only* used tactics so far, and I haven't written any pure term proofs.  Thanks!

Comment: To build on this answer and the comment, while it is generally not advisable, it is possible (and actually done by advanced users) to produce *definitions* using tactic mode. If you have multiple terms of a given type in context, it's important to be able to choose precisely which one you want to use in the given definition. The `exact` tactic lets you do precisely this. (Of course, for proofs this distinction doesn't matter.)

Comment: Whether it's "advisable" to use tactics to produce definitions depends on what you're doing.  In HoTT we do this all the time and it would be very difficult to do without.  Of course, Lean 3+ isn't HoTT-compatible, but I don't see any reason to avoid it in principle.

Comment: Adam, isn’t that exactly my example, building the `fst` function?

Comment: Yes, of course Joachim! Sorry, I should have clarified. And to respond to Mike's comment, the same is true in Lean, but we do tend to advise *new users* against making definitions using tactics.